# Generators are only available for Ionic 2 projects

Tags: ionic, ionic2

Não consigo resolver seguinte erro:

```
Generators are only available for Ionic 2 projects (CLI v2.1.8)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.8
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 3.16
Node Version: v6.9.1
Xcode version: Not installed
```

já tentei atualizar a CLI: (não obtive sucesso)

```
ionic lib update
```

Consegui da seguinte maneira:

```
ionic start example blank --v2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque você está tentando utilizar um generator em um projeto Ionic 1, quando o generator do Ionic só dá suporte para a versão 2.